# Sitecore SQL Admin Password Reset

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sitecore

I've deployed Sitecore 9.1 as a PaaS solution using "Developer" configuration. This created the required app services and databases. I have now forgotten the SQL Admin password. I understand that I can reset the SQL Admin password from Azure portal. Before resetting that password, I wanted to check if doing so would break the connectivity from App Services to the DB. If the connectivity breaks, where do I go in the app service to update the SQL Connection string password?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

If the app is using the admin account then surely it would reset. Since your using Sitecore 9.1 it’s probably not using the admin account as the default installer provision new sql accounts.

To check which account the app is using, checkout the connectionSting.config located at wwwroot/{app}/app_data/ConnectionString.config